# PostMessage sends additional WM_CHAR message

Tags: c#

I have two troubles when I send message using PostMessage. Before using it, I сaught messages from the keyboard using Spy++

[image]

[image]

I want to send the same messages from my application. I create a sample with messages params from screenshot above.

Method:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, UIntPtr wParam, UIntPtr lParam);
```

Ussage:

```
PostMessage(window, (uint)WindowsMessagesFlags.WM_KEYDOWN, (UIntPtr)0x00000020, (UIntPtr)0x00390001);
Thread.Sleep(15);
PostMessage(window, (uint)WindowsMessagesFlags.WM_KEYUP, (UIntPtr)0x00000020, (UIntPtr)0x00390001);
```

1. The message that sends my app always has wParam = 0, instead of (UIntPtr) 0x00390001
2. The message that sends my app also generates the WM_CHAR message.

Log from Spy++ when send messages from app:
[image]

What I did wrong? How to prevent sending WM_CHAR message, from my app and fix wParam?

Comment: fUp:0 tells you about the mistake, wrong flags.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keyup#parameters

Comment: But when I use keyboard I also have fUp:0

Comment: No, the screenshot clearly shows fUp:1 for the WM_KEYUP message.

Comment: Yep. You are right. I must use 0xC0390001 instead of 0x00390001